# There is preset data series when using addchart

Tags: excel, vba

I run the following code lines:

```
Sub spaghetti2()


Set MyCht = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=240, XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmooth)



End Sub
```

and here s the result : 
[image]

Now what should i do to create a chart without any data in it. (I think it might have something to do with cache or variable history, does vba of excel has some kind of workspace memory? and would clearing that workspace work? )

Comment: Empty charts don't make any sense. You need to set a source data range. Eg. `MyCht.DrawingObject.Chart.SetSourceData Range("A1")`. The actual used source data is based on the cell selection before you run `AddChart2`. So if you select the correct data range before you run `AddChart2` the chart should look correct too.

Comment: After working with this issue some more I realized that if I click in a cell outside of the range of data in that sheet, the chart that is created by the code will be empty.